# Why does this addition to my ANTLR4 grammar break an unrelated rule alternative?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am parsing Magic cards using ANTLR4 (org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0). This minimized version is able to parse abilities such as `Enchant creature`, `Enchant black creature`, ..., as well as `Protection from creatures`, `Protection from legendary creatures`, ...

Now I'm trying to enable `Protection from black`, which gives me problems.

I have the following lexer & parser grammars, along with a test class:

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar OracleLexer;

Black: 'black';
Creature: 'creature';
Creatures: 'creatures';
Enchant: 'enchant';
From: 'from';
Legendary: 'legendary';
Protection: 'protection';

WS: [ \t\f\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Parser:

```
parser grammar OracleParser;

options {
  tokenVocab = OracleLexer;
}

line:
  keywordAbility EOF;

keywordAbility:
  Enchant singularObject #Enchant |
    Protection From pluralObject #Protection;                   // (A)
//  Protection From (pluralObject | objectQuality) #Protection; // (B)



singularObject:
  objectQuality? Creature;

pluralObject:
  objectQuality? Creatures;



objectQuality:
  cardtypeQuality+? |
  supertypeQuality+ cardtypeQuality*? |
  colorQuality+ supertypeQuality* cardtypeQuality*?;

colorQuality:
  Black;

supertypeQuality:
  Legendary;

cardtypeQuality:
  Creature;
```

Test class:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import static java.util.Collections.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;


public class OracleParserTest {
    private static final List<String> ruleNames = unmodifiableList(asList(OracleParser.ruleNames));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        parse("Enchant creature");
        parse("Enchant black creature");
        parse("Protection from black");
        parse("Protection from black creatures");
    }

    private static void parse(String ability) throws RecognitionException {
        OracleLexer lexer = new OracleLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(ability.toLowerCase()));
        lexer.removeErrorListeners();
        lexer.addErrorListener(new BailErrorListener());

        OracleParser parser = new OracleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());

        RuleContext ctx = parser.line();

        System.out.println(ctx.toStringTree(ruleNames));
        ctx.inspect(ruleNames);
    }
}
```

In the parser, there is the `keywordAbility` rule in which I changed alternative `(A)` to `(B)`, and suddenly, I can't match `Enchant black creature` any more. Here are all the parse trees in text form, if it helps:

```
 original strings
Enchant creature
Enchant black creature
Protection from black
Protection from black creatures

 parse trees variant (A)
(line (keywordAbility enchant (singularObject creature)) <EOF>)
(line (keywordAbility enchant (singularObject (objectQuality (colorQuality black)) creature)) <EOF>)
 does not parse - expected
(line (keywordAbility protection from (pluralObject (objectQuality (colorQuality black)) creatures)) <EOF>)

 parse trees variant (B)
(line (keywordAbility enchant (singularObject creature)) <EOF>)
 does not parse - problem!
(line (keywordAbility protection from (objectQuality (colorQuality black))) <EOF>)
(line (keywordAbility protection from (pluralObject (objectQuality (colorQuality black)) creatures)) <EOF>)
```

Here's the stack trace for `Enchant black creature`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy.recover(BailErrorStrategy.java:51)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParser.objectQuality(OracleParser.java:462)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParser.singularObject(OracleParser.java:235)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParser.keywordAbility(OracleParser.java:161)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParser.line(OracleParser.java:79)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParserTest.parse(OracleParserTest.java:49)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParserTest.main(OracleParserTest.java:35)
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.NoViableAltException
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.noViableAlt(ParserATNSimulator.java:1532)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.execATNWithFullContext(ParserATNSimulator.java:816)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.execATN(ParserATNSimulator.java:701)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.predictATN(ParserATNSimulator.java:389)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict(ParserATNSimulator.java:346)
    at net.slightlymagic.laterna.oracle.grammar.OracleParser.objectQuality(OracleParser.java:440)
    ... 5 more
```

How do I get the grammar to parse this ability (again), and why does it not work as it is?

(I have tried removing the BailErrorStrategy, which makes it work but also results in 90% of all Magic abilities parsing as false positives, and does not explain why the ability worked before. Does/should BailErrorStrategy interfere with backtracking at all?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 4 does not use backtracking (the runtime library literally does not contain code for such a feature in any form).

I am not able to reproduce this using the test at the end of this message. My guess is one of the following is causing the problem:

1. You added `BailErrorStrategy` to your lexer. It was never intended to be used in this manner. Instead, follow the suggestions in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26108531/138304) to defer syntax errors to the parser exclusively.
2. You might be using an old version of ANTLR which suffers from a bug that has since been fixed.
3. The problem appears only when using separate lexer and parser grammars (the test uses a combined grammar).

**Test case:**

```
@Test
public void testCardParsing() throws Exception {
    String grammar =
        "grammar Oracle;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "line @init{setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());} @after {System.out.println($ctx.toStringTree(this));} :\n" +
        "  keywordAbility EOF;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "keywordAbility:\n" +
        "  Enchant singularObject #Enchant |\n" +
        "//  Protection From pluralObject #Protection;                   // (A)\n" +
        "    Protection From (pluralObject | objectQuality) #Protection; // (B)\n" +
        "\n" +
        "singularObject:\n" +
        "  objectQuality? Creature;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "pluralObject:\n" +
        "  objectQuality? Creatures;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "objectQuality:\n" +
        "  cardtypeQuality+? |\n" +
        "  supertypeQuality+ cardtypeQuality*? |\n" +
        "  colorQuality+ supertypeQuality* cardtypeQuality*?;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "colorQuality:\n" +
        "  Black;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "supertypeQuality:\n" +
        "  Legendary;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "cardtypeQuality:\n" +
        "  Creature;\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Black: 'black';\n" +
        "Creature: 'creature';\n" +
        "Creatures: 'creatures';\n" +
        "Enchant: 'enchant';\n" +
        "From: 'from';\n" +
        "Legendary: 'legendary';\n" +
        "Protection: 'protection';\n" +
        "\n" +
        "WS: [ \\t\\f\\r\\n]+ -> skip;";

    String input = "enchant creature";
    String found = execParser("Oracle.g4", grammar, "OracleParser", "OracleLexer", "line", input, true);
    assertEquals("(line (keywordAbility enchant (singularObject creature)) <EOF>)\n", found);
    assertNull(stderrDuringParse);

    input = "enchant black creature";
    found = execParser("Oracle.g4", grammar, "OracleParser", "OracleLexer", "line", input, false);
    assertEquals("(line (keywordAbility enchant (singularObject (objectQuality (colorQuality black)) creature)) <EOF>)\n", found);
    assertNull(stderrDuringParse);

    input = "protection from black";
    found = execParser("Oracle.g4", grammar, "OracleParser", "OracleLexer", "line", input, false);
    assertEquals("(line (keywordAbility protection from (objectQuality (colorQuality black))) <EOF>)\n", found);
    assertNull(stderrDuringParse);

    input = "protection from black creatures";
    found = execParser("Oracle.g4", grammar, "OracleParser", "OracleLexer", "line", input, false);
    assertEquals("(line (keywordAbility protection from (pluralObject (objectQuality (colorQuality black)) creatures)) <EOF>)\n", found);
    assertNull(stderrDuringParse);
}
```

Comment: The `BailErrorListener` is a custom class of mine that I forgot to include; as the exception is thrown in the parser, it should not be the culprit. I will check whether I use the latest version in my Maven build and report back, and will try with your test case.
If you don't mind the question, I assume that `adaptivePredict` somehow does what most parsers would do using backtracking?

Comment: Upgrading to 4.3 solved the issue, thanks! I'm somewhat embarrassed that I didn't think of that...